# Java nested exception SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, php, ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore

I'm having issue to communicate between the Cisco CUCM and a script on another server since the CUCM's certificate have been changed.

**I'm running the commands from the server towards the Cisco CUCM**

After troubleshooting it, Php sends me this :

```
nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

As I know it's SSL related, I imported the new CUCM certificate onto the Debian server which is hosting the script.

**By the way, i'm working with OpenSSL 0.9.8o (01 Jun 2010)**

I added it to every keystore that I found on the machine (I found 5different keystores) and reloaded with "dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates" (even if I don't know if the system is using it)

The fact is that I cannot really change the scripts, I'm in charge of the system, not the code.

Which is interesting is this :

**1/ Running the command openssl s_client -showcerts -connect ip:443** 
Is telling me :

```
CONNECTED
...
verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
```

**2/ Running the same command but adding "-CApath /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts"**

```
CONNECTED
...
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

I should conclude that the script (and openssl by default) is not using the CA keystore locate in the java directory

**Am I right ?
If I am, how do I know where is the used keystore located ?**

Comment: In general, when you ask openssl related questions you should include the version. Please provide the output of `openssl version`

Comment: Also, where are you running the command from? Note that when you add `-CApath` to your command, it uses the path to verify the remote certs and not to supply the CA certs during the hadshake.

Comment: Thanks, I added all the infos.
What do you mean ? It still uses the "default cert location" for the handshake ?

Comment: Try the solution here https://blogs.oracle.com/gc/entry/unable_to_find_valid_certification